# How to rasterize a view from another thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I am converting a view into a bitmap image. This is called rasterization. I tried to offload the rasterization to another thread, so my UI doesn't freeze for split second during the rasterization. To my chagrin, attempting to do so does the opposite: it freezes the entire app forever. Activity indicators stop spinning, buttons stop responding to taps, etc...

```
- (void)setContainerView:(UIView*)containerView
{        
    dispatch_async(
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
        ^{
            UIImage* hugeImage = containerView.rasterizedImage;
            dispatch_async(
                dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
                ^ {
                    self.someImageView.image = hugeImage;
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

The rasterize function is defined in a UIView category:

```
- (UIImage*)rasterizedImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

This function runs fine on the main thread. Why would it freeze the UI when run on another thread?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all UIKit objects are not thread-safe. You CAN'T run them in a separate thread without either getting undefined results or locking up/crashing your program.

Comment: Is there any alternative? I have some other image effects, such as Gaussian blurring, that are taking half a second to complete. It makes user interaction less responsive. That's why I'd like to offload all these image effects to a different thread.